# Regarding asynchronous Task, why is a Wait() required to catch OperationCanceledException?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library

I'm following the example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) to learn about asynchronous tasks.  I've modified the code to write some output of the task's work vs. the main work.  The output will look like this:

[image]

I noticed that if I remove the Wait() call, the program runs the same except I can't catch the exception that's thrown when the task is canceled.  Can someone explain what's going on behind the scenes requiring the Wait() in order to hit the catch block?

One warning, the Visual Studio debugger will erroneously stop on the `Console.WriteLine(" - task work");` line with the message "OperationCanceledException was unhandled by user code".  When that happens, just click Continue or hit F5 to see the rest of the program run.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/11/9946736.aspx for details.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
     var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

    // Delegate representing work that the task will do.
     var workDelegate 
            = (Action)
              (
                () =>
                   {
                       while (true)
                       {
                          cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
              // "If task has been cancelled, throw exception to return"

          // Simulate task work
                  Console.WriteLine(" - task work"); //Visual Studio  
           //erroneously stops on exception here. Just continue (F5). 
           //See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/11/9946736.aspx
                          Thread.Sleep(100);
                       }
                   }
              );


     try
     {
     // Start the task
         var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(workDelegate, cancellationToken);

      // Simulate main work
         for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("main work");
             Thread.Sleep(200);
         }

       // Cancel the task
         tokenSource.Cancel();

       // Why is this Wait() necessary to catch the exception?
       // If I reomve it, the catch (below) is never hit, 
       //but the program runs as before.
          task.Wait();
     }
     catch (AggregateException e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         foreach (var innerException in e.InnerExceptions)
         Console.WriteLine(innerException.Message);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
     Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the exception is thrown by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, it propagates out of your `Task` delegate. At that point, it is captured by the framework and added to the list of exceptions for that `Task`. At the same time, that `Task` is transitioned to the `Faulted` state.

Ideally, you want to observe all your `Task` exceptions. If you're using `Task`s as part of the task-based asynchronous pattern, then at some point you should `await` the `Task`, which propagates the first exception on the `Task`. If you're using `Task`s as part of the task parallel library, then at some point you should call `Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`, which propagates all the exceptions on the `Task`, wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

If you do not observe a `Task` exception, then when the `Task` is finalized, the runtime will raise `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` and then ignore the exception. (This is the .NET 4.5 behavior; the pre-4.5 behavior would raise `UnobservedTaskException` and then terminate the process).

In your case, you don't wait for the task to complete, so you exit the try/catch block. Some time later, `UnobservedTaskException` is raised and then the exception is ignored.

Comment: I see two answers saying that the program gets past the catch block before the exception is thrown.  Is that different than the ignored `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` you mention here, or are both occurring?

Comment: Both. Since you're not waiting for the task to complete, you exit the `try`/`catch` block. Some time later, `UnobservedTaskException` is raised and then the exception is ignored.

Comment: This is great information. Did you learn it from the API docs and MSDN articles? I've read a handful, but didn't get a clear view of things like Tasks being associated with a list of exceptions, or the UnobservedTaskException. Or perhaps there's a good book. Thanks.

Comment: Mostly from Stephen Toub's articles on the [Parallel Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wait for the task to finish, your program will continue running and thus you will have passed the catch-block.

If on the other hand you would `await` the task, the exception would still be caught

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wait for `task` to complete, your program will exit (or at least leave that area of execution) before the exception is thrown.

If the main thread is already at

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

it will not "back up" to the `try/catch` block.

Comment: That would explain it.  Does the example behavior come down to how the task is time sliced into the main program, where it could conceivably be caught if the time slices were scheduled "just so"?  Or, is `Wait()` the return path for the exception and there would be no way for it to propagate otherwise? (Or, are async exceptions handled independently of the call stack?) Thanks.